# JAVA- Printing out LinkedLists in an ArrayList

Tags: java, overriding

I am trying to print out the elements in my ArrayList that looks like

`static ArrayList<LinkedList> listy = new ArrayList<>();`

I tried to create a function called PrintTest()

```
public static void pTest() {
String [] top;
for (LinkedList i: listy) {
    
    //i.show();
    System.out.println(i.toString());
```

However, I am still getting when I call printTest()

```
LinkedList@15975490
LinkedList@6b143ee9
LinkedList@1936f0f5
LinkedList@6615435c
LinkedList@4909b8da
LinkedList@3a03464
LinkedList@2d3fcdbd
LinkedList@617c74e5
```

Do I need to iterator over this once more? I am confused on how to go about this. Can I override toString()? I can't seem to get it to work

Here is my linkedlist implementation code

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    Node tail;
    
    
    public String getFirst() {
        Node node = head;
        if (node.next == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        else {
        return node.data;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void insert(String data) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            
        }
        else {
            Node n = head;
            while(n.next !=null) {
                n = n.next;
                
            }
            n.next = node;
        }
    }
    
    public void insertAtStart(String data) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        
    }
    
    public void insertAt(int index, String data) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        
        if(index == 0) {
            insertAtStart(data);
        }
        else {
            Node n = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            node.next = n.next;
            n.next = node;
        }
    }
    
    public void deleteAt(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        else {
            Node n = head;
            Node n1 = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
                n = n.next;  
            }
            n1 = n.next;
            n.next = n1.next;
            //System.out.println("n1 " + n1.data);
            n1 = null;
        }
    }
    
    public int size() {
        int count =0;
        Node pos = head;
        while (pos != null) {
            count++;
            pos = pos.next;
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    
    public void remove(String s) {
        Node node = head;
        while (!node.data.equals(s)) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        if (node.next == null) {
            node.data = null;
        }
        else {

            node.data = node.next.data;
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }

                //System.out.println("n1 " + n1.data);
    }
    
    public void show() {
        Node node = head;
        while(node.next != null) {
            System.out.println(node.data);
            node = node.next;
            
        }
        System.out.println(node.data);
```

Comment: When you create your own `LinkedList` impl, then you need to overwrite `toString()` or inherit it from somewhere.

Comment: It is printing hashcode value of the element. What is testy if your arraylist is listy?

Comment: What exactly is `LinkedList`? Apparently not [`java.util.LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html). If you are using another such class from another 3rd-party library, say so. If you are writing your own class, show the source code. Voting to close as there is not enough detail to justify an Answer.

Comment: @VishwajitRahatal I fixed it i am sorry.

Comment: @Basil Bourque. I coded my own version of LinkedList to help me understand how it works and I am using that

Answer (score 2):

In java, every class inherits the Object class. In the Object class default definition for the toString method is hashcode. When you are calling toString method, you need to define by yourself.

```
class LinkedList{
    int value;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

I think you can go through this article to get more understanding.[Explanation For toString](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method)

Comment: @Tom I have updated the code. Thanks for correcting